# How to create virtual monitor with xrandr without increasing HDMI screen width?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, multiple-monitors, xorg, xrandr

When I run `xrandr` to create a virtual monitor, it doesn't really creates a virtual monitor. Instead, it increases the width of my HDMI monitor and enable some type of "scrolling" behavior. I'm able to connect to the third monitor via TeamViewer for example but it makes really hard to work with this wrong behavior. And I already spent two or three days searching, testing.

This is my current state and setup:

```sh
xrandr | grep ' connected'
```

```sh
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+1368+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
eDP1 connected 1368x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
VIRTUAL1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I enabled only one virtual head in `20-intel.conf` file:

```sh
cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

```sh
Section "Device"
  Identifier "intelgpu0"
  Driver "intel"
  Option "VirtualHeads" "1"
EndSection
```

I added a mode for `VIRTUAL1`:

```sh
xrandr --addmode VIRTUAL1 1920x1080
```

And the command I run to create my monitor set is:

```sh
xrandr \
  --output eDP1 --mode 1368x768 --pos 0x0 \
  --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1368x0 --right-of eDP1 --primary \
  --output VIRTUAL1 --mode 1920x1080 --right-of eDP1
```

My workflow before executing `xrandr` commands:

[image: Workflow before executing xrandr commands]

And this is the screenshot after I run these commands:

[image: Workflow after I create virtual monitor]

**Is it possible to fix this strange HDMI behavior?** Because it makes it difficult to work, hides the extensions, I have to drag the mouse to scroll the visible area to the other monitor and come back when I need to. It's really bad. I made a video but there's no way to upload it here in Ask Ubuntu. In the video I show the strange scrolling behavior. Thank you if you can watch.

##### **[Strange behavior after creating virtual monitor with `xrandr`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zWBpSY73_lhkLrlEu-wGREOva5CIb0bF/view?usp=sharing)**